# Schedule tasks are triggered from which server?

Tags: marklogic

I have a task that takes more than 10 mins to return the result. Since, the default response time limit is 10 mins., it fails to return the result and query execution is timed out. I want to increase the time limit but don't know for which server.

Answer (score 3):

Scheduled tasks always run on `Task Servers`. More specifically, they run on Task Servers of `Hosts` within the same `Group` as the `Scheduled Tasks`. Depending on configuration, it could even be tied down to just one of the hosts within the Group, which should show if you inspect the scheduled tasks from `Admin UI`.

In any case, you can adjust the default and max time limit from Task Server page of the appropriate Group in the Admin UI.

Alternatively, you can adjust the time limit programmatically for requests individually from within the task using [`xdmp:set-request-time-limit`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:set-request-time-limit). It allows more refined control what tasks should get more time to complete. Using that you can increase the time limit till the `max time limit`, which defaults to 3600 sec (1 hour).

HTH!

Comment: You mean if I put this xdmp code at the top of my xquery code, it will increase the time limit for my code only? Because that will do the job for me and I don't have to change the general settings.Can you provide an xquery example ?

Comment: Yep, put something like this `xdmp:set-request-time-limit(3600)` at the start of your code, and you're done. Where exactly depends on your code, as long as it is invoked before long processing is kicked off..